# What does it mean for a material's elasticity to be non-linear?

Tags: definition, elasticity, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain, non-linear-systems

Hooke's law only applies to materials with linear elasticity, usually for small displacements.

Now, if you imagine having a material that does not deform permanently when crossing a specific limit, then would it be non-linear? What is what defines non-linearity? Is it always linear for small displacements? And when you calculate the integral for elastic potential energy, would it matter if it is non-linear or it is assumed to be considered unimportant due to the integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several questions in one, I will try to answer them.

1. When is a material non-elastic?

   From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperelastic_material):

   > A hyperelastic or Green elastic material is a type of constitutive model for ideally elastic material for which the stress–strain relationship derives from a strain energy density function.

   So, a material is inelastic when this condition does not hold. This usually means that you have some kind of energy dissipation.
2. Now, if you imagine having a material that does not deform permanently when crossing a specific limit, then would it be non-linear?

   Yes.
3. Is it always linear for small displacements?

   For smooth stress-strain relationships you can define a tangent hyperplane that locally approximate your relationship.
4. What is what defines non-linearity?

   In elasticity you can have geometrical non-linearities (large strains and deformations), material nonlinearities (nonlinear relationships between stresses and strains) and boundary condition nonlinearities.